# Can zed/malphite go through Azir's ulti?

Tags: league-of-legends

When Azir uses his ultimate, I've read and seen that dashes aren't able to go through. But is Zed's shadow supposed to go through? I mean, it's not a dash but it's not as fast as a blink either. For example you can't safeguard (lee sin ) over Azir's wall. Can Malphite's ultimate go through Azir's wall? I haven't tested it yet. Malphite's ultimate isn't a dash or hardly a blink either.

Comment: Malph's ult 'unstoppable force' does go through for a fact. As for zed, it should as I think it's a delayed blink

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes both of these spells are able to pass through the wall. Zeds Ultimate is a blink that also makes him untargetable for a short moment while Malphites unstoppable force renders him immune to All forms of Crowd Control.

In general You can say that all dashes will go through **as long as a champion is immune to crowd control**. This means that dashes which provide you with a CC immunity will always go through (Malphite Ultimate, Nocturne Ultimate) while other normal dashes that would normally be blocked by the wall such as Yasuos E can also pass the wall while the champion is immune to CC (Morgana Black shield).

Fun fact: Grabbing someone with Blitzcrank or Thresh Lantern will also prevent the target from getting past the wall.

Answer (score 4):

Zed can, since it is more a blink than a move. Malphs Ult can go trough the wall too, at least i saw it once, not sure if it was a bug or intended. To extend the answer: Vi's ult can go through the wall too.

Answer (score 0):

Any skill that renders the user untargetable can pass through it. Depressingly this includes Fizz's E and Maokai's W making it horrible to play against them.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Please avoid creating answers with information that's already present in other answers. Visit the [Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about our site's rules :)